# Slow compilation time with Xcode 11

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm using the build time with Timing summary of Xcode to see what file are long to compile and I notice that most file takes about 13 seconds to compile, and some longer. And example is a file that has only this:

```
import Foundation

enum PrefType: String {
    case move = "move"
    case backStory = "backStory"
    case rightStory = "rightStory"
}
```

and this one takes 50 seconds... I don't get it.

This happens when I do a clean and build. Overall it takes around 7-8minutes. Otherwise with small change, it's 3-4 minutes... Which to me is still crazy long. Anyone has a clue?

I already turn on the new xcode build system and the recommended flag to speed up the process.. That didn't help much.

Comment: Not seeing this. Created new project - iOS single view - added new file, pasted your code in and it immediately compiled. It's hard to *not* downvote and/or flag your question.... It's vague to the point of not being able to duplicate. For instance, what exact version of Xcode? Are these files local? Are there 3rd party APIs involved? I understand your frustration, but maybe start with a new project and add your files in?